# How to make compiled __init__ module extensions work properly?

Tags: python, compilation, cython

I'm using the 64-bit version of python 3.3 and cython 0.18 on Windows 7.

I've encountered a problem that is thoroughly described [here](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.devel/135764)

One issue that was not discussed in the linked thread was, that the python's distutils called the link command (*link.exe*) with an option to export (this is only needed on Windows) a symbol named *PyInit_[module name]* but, if the module name was ***__init__*** the cython-created C file only specified a symbol with name *PyInit_[package name]* and the linker gave back this error: *LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol*.

Fortunately, I managed to fix this issue in the *build_ext* module.

The problem that remains is that a compiled ***__init__**.pyd* module of *mypackage* containing an import statement like

```
import math
```

Throws an

```
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

When *mypackage* is imported (no matter from where it is imported). Without import statements it works as expected though.

If anyone has a fix, workaround or information that could solve this problem or could explain why it's not (yet) solvable please, share your knowledge.

Comment: Hi! Could you explain how you solved the LNK2001 error? I am having the same problem cythonizing __init__.py files.

Comment: @ SuperGeo See for example: [How to compile \_\_init\_\_.py file using cython on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58797673/how-to-compile-init-py-file-using-cython-on-windows)