# How to compile __init__.py file using cython on Windows

Tags: python, windows, cython

When I compile an arbitrary __init__.py file on Windows with `setup.py build_ext --inplace` command, it has an unresolvable external symbol error (i.e. "LINK : error LNK2001: An unresolvable external symbol PyInit___init__").

The local environment:

```
python3.7,
Cython 0.29.14,
window10 x64,
Microsoft Visual Studio 2017,
```

ctest/__init__.py

```
# cython: language_level=3
print('__init__')
```

setup.py

```py
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize


def compile_code(name, filename):
    setup(
        name=name,
        ext_modules=cythonize(filename),
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    compile_code('a', 'ctest/__init__.py')
```

The information printed by the terminal:

```
Compiling ctest/__init__.py because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing ctest/__init__.py
running build_ext
building 'ctest.__init__' extension
creating build
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\ctest
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Id:\py37\include -Id:\py37\incl
ude "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Pro
gram Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\includ
e\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcctest/__init__
.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\ctest/__init__.obj
__init__.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTU
AC:NO /LIBPATH:d:\py37\Libs /LIBPATH:D:\ENVS\cpytrantest\libs /LIBPATH:D:\ENVS\cpytrantest\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC
\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x6
4" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit___init__ build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\ctest/__init__.obj /OUT:C:\Users\76923\Deskto
p\cpythonrecord\ctest\__init__.cp37-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\ctest\__init__.cp37-win_amd64.lib
LINK : error LNK2001: An unresolvable external symbol PyInit___init__
build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\ctest\__init__.cp37-win_amd64.lib : fatal error LNK1120: An external command that cannot be parsed
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
```

Comment: I would rather not cythonize/compile __init__.py. It seems to work on Linux but there are problems on Windows.

Comment: @ead Thank you for your reply. I executed the same command on Linux and it worked, much as I wish, but I need to run it on the window now...

Comment: That might be interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32067984/5769463 implies that it kind of accidentally works - but should one rely on it? However, `__init__.py` is not really a module, so why not leave it uncompiled? What is the benefit of compiling it in the first place?

Comment: I recall seeing that you can make it work on Windows if you change symbol visibility (or something like that, I can't remember the details). It does seem mostly pointless though

Comment: @ead Thanks again.How could that not be a good solution.There's just a little bit of code in the \__init__.py file, it's fine not to compile it.Maybe it's because it worked on Linux, but it's a problem on Windows, so I'm looking for a solution about it.

Comment: @DavidW Thank you for your reply. You're right. It is only because the init file did not compile successfully before (there is no \__init__.py file in the compiled folder) that the program failed to run, so I started to look for methods.Of course I can copy the \__init__.py  file over here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe this behaviour might be viewed as a small bug in `distutils`-package (as pointed out by @DavidW there is this open issue: https://bugs.python.org/issue35893). However, it also shows, that cythonizing/compiling `__init__.py` isn't very popular and uses some undocumented implementation details which might change in the future, so it could be wiser to refrain from meddling with `__init__.py`.

But if you must...

---

When a package is imported explicitly, e.g.

```
import ctest
```

or implicitly, e.g.

```
import ctest.something
```

The [`FileFinder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.FileFinder) will see that a package, and not a module, is imported and [will try to load](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py#L1420) `ctest/__init__.py` instead of `ctest.py` (which most likely doesn't exists):

```
    # Check if the module is the name of a directory (and thus a package).
    if cache_module in cache:
        base_path = _path_join(self.path, tail_module)
        for suffix, loader_class in self._loaders:
            init_filename = '__init__' + suffix
            full_path = _path_join(base_path, init_filename)
            if _path_isfile(full_path):
                return self._get_spec(loader_class, fullname, full_path, [base_path], target)
```

Used `suffix, loader_class` are for loading `__init__.so`, `__init__.py` and `__init__.pyc`  in this order (see also this [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56004885/5769463)). This means, `__init__.so` will be loaded instead of `__init__.py` if we manage to create one.

While `__init__.py` is executed, The property `__name__` is the name of the package, i.e. `ctest` in your case, and not `__init__` as one might think. Thus, the name of the init-function, Python-interpreter will call when loading the extension `__init__.so` is `PyInit_ctest` in your case (and not `PyInit___init__` as one might think).

The above explains, why it all works on Linux out-of-the-box. What about Windows?

The loader can only use symbols from a so/dll which aren't hidden. Per default all symbols built with gcc are visible, but not for VisualStudio on Windows - where all symbols are hidden per default (see e.g. this [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52216452/5769463)).

However, the init-function of a C-extension must be visible (and only the init-function) so it can be called with help of the loader - the solution is to export this symbol (i.e. `PyInit_ctest`) while linking, in your case it is the wrong `/EXPORT:PyInit___init__`-option for the linker.

The problem can be found in distutils, or more precise in [`build_ext`-class](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Lib/distutils/command/build_ext.py#L684):

```
def get_export_symbols(self, ext):
    """Return the list of symbols that a shared extension has to
    export.  This either uses 'ext.export_symbols' or, if it's not
    provided, "PyInit_" + module_name.  Only relevant on Windows, where
    the .pyd file (DLL) must export the module "PyInit_" function.
    """
    initfunc_name = "PyInit_" + ext.name.split('.')[-1]
    if initfunc_name not in ext.export_symbols:
        ext.export_symbols.append(initfunc_name)
    return ext.export_symbols
```

Here, sadly `ext.name` has `__init__` in it.

From here, one possible solution is easy : to override `get_export_symbols`, i.e. to add the following to your `setup.py`-file (read on for a even simpler version):

```
...
from distutils.command.build_ext import build_ext
def get_export_symbols_fixed(self, ext):
    names = ext.name.split('.')
    if names[-1] != "__init__":
        initfunc_name = "PyInit_" + names[-1]
    else:
        # take name of the package if it is an __init__-file
        initfunc_name = "PyInit_" + names[-2]
    if initfunc_name not in ext.export_symbols:
        ext.export_symbols.append(initfunc_name)
    return ext.export_symbols

# replace wrong version with the fixed:
build_ext.get_export_symbols = get_export_symbols_fixed
...
```

Calling `python setup.py build_ext -i` should be enough now (because `__init__.so` will be loaded rather than `__init__.py`).

---

However, as @DawidW has pointed out, Cython uses macro [`PyMODINIT_FUNC`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0b60f64e4343913b4931dc27379d9808e5b78fe1/Include/pyport.h#L670), which is defined as

```c
#define PyMODINIT_FUNC Py_EXPORTED_SYMBOL PyObject*
```

with [`Py_EXPORTED_SYMBOL`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0b60f64e4343913b4931dc27379d9808e5b78fe1/Include/exports.h#L6) being marked as visible/exported on Windows:

```c
#define Py_EXPORTED_SYMBOL __declspec(dllexport)
```

Thus, there is no need to mark the symbol as visible at the command line. Even worse, this is the reason for the [warning LNK4197](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37596516/5769463):

> __init__.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_ctest' specified multiple times;
> using first specification

as `PyInit_test` is marked as `__declspec(dllexport)` and exported via option `/EXPORT:` at the same time.

`/EXPORT:`-option will [be skipped by distutils](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/55aabee07501e1468082b3237620e4ecd75c5da6/Lib/distutils/_msvccompiler.py#L506), if `export_symbols` is empty, we can use even a simpler version of `command.build_ext`:

```
...
from distutils.command.build_ext import build_ext
def get_export_symbols_fixed(self, ext):
    pass  # return [] also does the job!

# replace wrong version with the fixed:
build_ext.get_export_symbols = get_export_symbols_fixed
...
```

This is even better than the first version, as it also fixes warning LNK4197!

Comment: @ead It seems like this should be taken care of by [`PyMODINIT_FUNC`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0b60f64e4343913b4931dc27379d9808e5b78fe1/Include/pyport.h#L670). Would a simpler version that didn't add the `initfunc_name` also work?

Comment: @DavidW I think you are right. I have no possibility to check that right now, but if I remember right, this is the reason one gets warning LNK4197 from the linker on Windows: the symbol `PyInit_XXX` is once declared as `__declspec(dllexport)` and once via `/EXPORT:`.  One of them would be enough.

Comment: @ead I guess it's probably there as a backup for people writing there own C API modules who omit PyMODINIT_FUNC, but anyway... doesn't really matter.

Comment: Here's a link to the bug report for this https://bugs.python.org/issue35893

Answer (score 1):

This is a very tentative answer because I have no easy way of testing it on Windows, so if it's wrong then let me know and I'll delete it.

Can you try running (on the commend line):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:d:\py37\Libs /LIBPATH:D:\ENVS\cpytrantest\libs /LIBPATH:D:\ENVS\cpytrantest\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_ctest build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\ctest/__init__.obj /OUT:C:\Users\76923\Desktop\cpythonrecord\ctest\__init__.cp37-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-md64-3.7\Release\ctest\__init__.cp37-win_amd64.lib
```

All I've done is taken the compilation command that distutils generated and replaced `/EXPORT:PyInit___init__` with `/EXPORT:PyInit_ctest`. The `/EXPORT` is a Windows specific compiler option that doesn't get added on Linux. It looks like either distutils or Cython passes the name `PyInit___init__` to MSVC, but if I look in the actual generated C file then the name appears to be `PyInit_ctest`, hence the undefined symbol.

If that workaround (doing the compilation independently of distutils) works then you should report the bug to either the distutils or the Cython bug tracker (probably Cython) with these details and hopefully it can be fixed.

Comment: It's quite possible that this answer will only get you as far as the issue in your linked question, in which case I don't know if it's worth keeping

Comment: I don't know when it should execute, when I execute it directly at the terminal or after I execute `setup.py build_ext --inplace` command(It will generate `build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\ctest\__init__.obj`,`__init__.c`and Invalid file `ctest\__init__.cp37-win_amd64.pyd`), it prints `LINK : fatal error LNK1181: Unable to open input file “build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\ctest\\__init__.obj”`, right

Comment: @pppig I'm afraid I don't know then. I don't have Python and MSVC installed on Windows so I can't easily test anything, and this answer was a bit of a guess. My feeling is that it is the right direction to go, but I can't help any further. What I'll do is convert the answer to "community wiki" so it's easier for other people to edit it and make suggestions - if you're lucky someone else will have some ideas.