Django compiling to pyc and running server
Ok so i run
python -m compileall .

However the generated files are in pycache
manage.cpython-311.pyc
and
urls.cpython-311
my issue is when i run
python manage.cpython-311.pyc runserver

I keep getting the error
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1126, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1140, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings'

I am not the brightest django developer. However, i would appreciate if someone shares with me how to fix this issue.

I don't really see any reason to compile python files: Python generates cache files when running Python, so on the fly.

One reason for me is to hide the original code. Do you if running pyc files have any performance implication? Like faster or slower.

decompilers can just convert it back (except for comments), so that will not work a lot. security by obscurity is typically not a good idea.

the performance boost will work at most once: when compiling the file to cache for the first time, and even then, typically only save perhaps a few milliseconds. So the difference is almost none.

Got you. I have another question, so I have tried this method to compile to pyc files.
On another post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70563102/install-a-django-application-for-a-client-and-protect-its-source-code-or-convert
It converted the code to c and pyd files. mainly manage.c manage.pyd, urls.c urls.pyd. Although I couldn't get it running. Is that different from compiling it to pyc or not.
Excuse me for these questions as I am trying to read and understand but still have a small grasp on the topic

When you run Python code (and it is able to and not instructed otherwise) the interpreter will compile the imports to .pyc files and store them in the __pycache__ folder.
On the next run the interpreter will consider these files and if they fit the source file, use them instead of repeating the compilation phase.
The files in __pycache__ are not meant to be run directly, though you can do that. In your case running the file from __pycache__ moves the import base there and all the imports will fail without extra adjustments.
The compileall call will manually do this compilation step. It saves a little time on first execution. This is helpful in certain situations, like deploying your code in a large number of containers, which are expected to have a short lifetime. In most deployments it's not worth the effort.
Conclusion: Run the source file (.py) and let the caching mechanism do its work in the background.
